# How to do Replace("\n", "<br />") in detailsview BoundField data control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a column stores memo type long text. In order to display the text correctly I need to format it with But the property of DataFormatString in boundfield data control not allow me to use this.

Comment: The value you pasted for your live example (`<Column />`) isn't rendering anything.  Is this supposed to be a hyperlink?

Comment: No,It's about gridview on asp.net

Comment: "does not allow" usually means there is some error message. May we know what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a template field s below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="some header" SortExpression="yourfield">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <%# (Eval("yourfield").ToString()).Replace("\n", "<br />") %>
          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TemplateField` to perform it;

```
public string TextFormatting(string text) 
{
        return text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
}

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SampleHeader">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <%# TextFormatting(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sample").ToString()) %>
          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```